# Getting a build result from git (using SourceTree)

Tags: git

I have a build server which is going to be doing several regression tests on code as soon as a commit happens. It would come quite in handy if the results of both the build and testing could be stored into a file which displays which aspects happened without error and which parts failed. For now I have this line of code which should be executed right after a commit happens:

```
git log -1 --format=fuller > result.txt
```

This line writes mandatory information into result.txt such as the date, commit, who made the commit, and the comment the committer added. Despite this, it says nothing about the result of the commit whether it succeeded or not.

Does anyone know the appropriate command for adding the result-data? Also, how can I automate the running of this commandline after committing?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What build server are you using? Jenkins with the Git plugin logs the sha that it's building along with the job console log. Others might have better features as well. Something else to keep in mind: it's possible for multiple builds of the same commit to have different results as well. (E.g. Network issues prevent downloading of required dependencies) therefore I would avoid conflating source control with build results.

Comment: Also, a Git commit is an event local to your machine. Publishing those commits to everyone else (including your build server) is done by a separate action of pushing to a remote repository that others are able to pull from. There is a checkbox to enable them to both happen with SourceTree, but they are distinct actions